# best way to store image references in text using mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

I have a text that contains multiple images.

Imagine it to be like

I like ((image1)) , ((image2)) and ((image3))

I am storing text in table Statements

```
St_ID|Text
```

I'm storing image path in Images

```
Img_ID|Path_On_Disk
```

I store the relation between text and image as

```
TI_ID(PK) | St_ID | Img_ID | ImageNumber
```

Here Image Number refers to the order like Image1, 2 and 3

So my questions are :

1. Is the format used in the text best way to point/refer to an image?
2. Is the database design efficient?
3. When I'm using this in PHP, I follow this :

   If a fetched string has a match for (( and )) then I know I have an image, look for the appropriate number and find it in the TI table using the St_ID and Image_number ELSE just print text.

I think this might not be the best way because we are going char by char in a long string and can affect efficiency. So what can be a better way if any?

Comment: can one text description describe ore than one image?

Comment: Yes, a text can have multiple images

Comment: 1. seems odd - what about a template engine, 2 yes.

Comment: I have no idea how a template engine works. Plus, I still have to leave 'meaningful' empty spaces in the text to load images later and store them in the db.

Comment: how about: I like <img src="script.php?image=1"> , <img src="script.php?image=2">  and <img src="script.php?image=3">

Comment: That is a good first step. But then how do I make it unique? image=1 would be there across a lot of texts and if I refer the primary id of my question along with the image number (which makes a unique combination) would it be safe ?